# Are products of quantum channels (CPTPMs) also quantum channels?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator

A quantum channel $\mathcal E$ is a completely positive trace preserving map.

Is $\mathcal E \otimes \mathcal F$ a quantum channel if $\mathcal E,\mathcal F$ are quantum channels?

**What I have:**

- It is sufficient to answer this for $\mathcal E \otimes \mathit{id}$ since $\mathcal E \otimes \mathcal F = (\mathcal E \otimes \mathit{id}) \circ (\mathit{id} \otimes \mathcal F)$.
- Complete positivity of $\mathcal E \otimes \mathit{id}$ follows by definton from complete positivity of $\mathcal E$.
- The fact that $\mathcal E\otimes\mathit{id}$ is trace preserving is equivalent to showing that the diamond norm (aka completely bounded trace norm) of $\mathcal E$ is 1. This is stated in [Watrous](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/TQI/TQI.3.pdf), Prop. 3.44.2. However, the proof of that property already assumes (as far as I could tell), that $\mathcal E \otimes \mathit{id}$ is a channel.

**Bonus questions:**

It would be great if the answer also covers completely positive trace *reducing* maps as well as infinite Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Which property of CP maps *are* you interested in, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first two points are correct, and the fact that $\mathcal E\otimes \mathrm{id}$ is trace preserving is simply a consequence of the fact that, for any state $\rho_{AB}$,

$$\mathrm{Tr}_B(\mathcal{E}_A\otimes \mathrm{id}_B(\rho_{AB}))=\mathcal{E}(\mathrm{Tr}_B(\rho_{AB})) $$
which is very easy to show either by writing down the partial trace explicitly or by realizing that $\mathrm{Tr}_B$ commutes with $\mathcal E_A$ as they act on different spaces. This works for both trace preservingness or trace non increasing-ness or any trace property you might think of.

Another way to show this is that if a channel is trace preserving on a basis of matrices then it is trace preserving on any state. You can write any $\rho_{AB}$ as

$$ \rho_{AB}=\sum_{ij}\lambda_{ij}\sigma_A^i\otimes \tau_B^j$$

for some matrices $\sigma_A^i$, $\tau_B^j$, hence

$$ \mathrm{Tr}(\mathcal{E}\otimes \mathcal F(\rho_{AB}))=\sum_{ij}\lambda_{ij}\mathrm{Tr}(\mathcal{E}(\sigma^i))\mathrm{Tr}(\mathcal{F(\tau^j)})$$

which clearly implies everything you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathcal E$ is a channel, then it can be expressed in terms of Kraus operators,
$$
\mathcal E(\rho) = \sum K_i\rho K_i^\dagger\ .
$$
Then, the map $\mathcal E\otimes I$ is of the form
$$
(\mathcal E\otimes I)(\rho) = \sum (K_i\otimes I)\rho(K_i\otimes I)^\dagger\ .
$$
It is thus also a channel, with Kraus operators $K_i\otimes I$. In particular, if $\mathcal E$ is trace-preserving, it is immediate to see that $\mathcal E\otimes I$ is trace-preserving.